# How would you scuttle a nuclear submarine in the 19th century?

Tags: alternate-history

Imagine a nuclear submarine arriving in 19th century Europe. Everyone on board agree the world is not ready for such power, and the ship and especially the nuclear weapons must be destroyed as thoroughly as possible. How would you approach the task?

Comment: Sink it in deep water and everything needed is already onboard

Comment: Does it have an autopilot?

Comment: And remember, the weapons are only good for a few years even if kept pristine.

Comment: Something to think about: the weapons are less likely to be an issue than the nuclear reactor(s). I suspect it would be trivial to disable nuclear weapons in a way 19th century people couldn't overcome... but you kinda can't turn a reactor off.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest - and probably best - method would be to stop the sub over a deep-sea trench.  The crew sets up a mechanism on a timer that would flood all of the sub's ballast tanks, then evacuates and closes and seals the hatches.

When the timer goes off, the sub begins to dive by itself.  When it passes crush depth, it will implode violently (Remember the [Titan implosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_submersible_implosion)?), likely destroying everything inside, including the modern weaponry.  Anything that survives will descend to the bottom of the deep-sea trench, where it will be many years before the technology exists to recover it, and that's only if anyone knows and remembers just where the sub sank.

By the time anyone could find the wreck and get down there to look, anything sensitive would have decayed to the point of uselessness.